# Customization of BrowserGallery in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

[I need to display the cards who got the marks in writtentest more than 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGfpv.png) . I have connected to the SQL Server database. PowerApps automatically created an app for my database. The data in the database is student details and written test marks. In my app, it shows all the students information. But I need to display only the students list who got more than 50 marks in written test. How to customize the card in BrowserGallery to get the required output. First of all, is it possible to customize the cards? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the BrowseGallery, and select the you'll see the expression that is listed in that property is already filtering your data source based on the search item the user can type:

[image]

The expression you have is probably something along these lines (I added spaces / indentation for clarity):

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(<yourDataSource>, TextSearchBox1.Text, "Name", "Email"),
    "Name",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

In PowerApps you can compose the expression, so instead of searching directly in your data source, you can also search over a *filtered* version of the data source, which is probably what you want. You can use the [Filter function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/tutorials/function-filter-lookup/) to only have the students that meet a certain condition. If the number of marks is in a column named "marks", you can rewrite the Items property to include it as well:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter(<yourDataSource>, marks > 50),
        TextSearchBox1.Text,
        "Name",
        "Email"),
    "Name",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```